# How do I make a layout with spaced EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I am implementing phone verification in my app. The user will input 4 values. This is what I need to look like:

[image]

How can I make this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this layout using `LinearLayout` with attribute `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Add 4 `EditText` inside `LinearLayout` and also add attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` to each `EditText` for equal `width`.

**Here is your desired layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_digit_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_digit_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_digit_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_digit_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_verify"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="verify"
        android:enabled="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**#.** If you want to `move` cursor `programmatically` and `enable/disable` VERIFY button depending on `input`, then add below code in your Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PinVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText inputDigitOne;
    EditText inputDigitTwo;
    EditText inputDigitThree;
    EditText inputDigitFour;
    Button buttonVerify;

    int digitCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin_verification);

        inputDigitOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_digit_one);
        inputDigitTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_digit_two);
        inputDigitThree = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_digit_three);
        inputDigitFour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_digit_four);
        buttonVerify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_verify);


        inputDigitOne.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    digitCount--;
                } else {
                    digitCount++;
                    inputDigitOne.clearFocus();

                    // Move cursor to second input field
                    inputDigitTwo.requestFocus();
                    inputDigitTwo.setCursorVisible(true);
                }

                toggleVerifyButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        inputDigitTwo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    digitCount--;
                } else {
                    digitCount++;
                    inputDigitTwo.clearFocus();

                    // Move cursor to third input field
                    inputDigitThree.requestFocus();
                    inputDigitThree.setCursorVisible(true);
                }

                toggleVerifyButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        inputDigitThree.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    digitCount--;
                } else {
                    digitCount++;
                    inputDigitThree.clearFocus();

                    // Move cursor to forth input field
                    inputDigitFour.requestFocus();
                    inputDigitFour.setCursorVisible(true);
                }

                toggleVerifyButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        inputDigitFour.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (count == 0)
                    digitCount--;
                else
                    digitCount++;

                toggleVerifyButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        // Verify
        buttonVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StringBuilder strPIN = new StringBuilder();
                strPIN.append(inputDigitOne.getText().toString());
                strPIN.append(inputDigitTwo.getText().toString());
                strPIN.append(inputDigitThree.getText().toString());
                strPIN.append(inputDigitFour.getText().toString());

                // Now verify PIN (Here I have used dummy PIN 1234 for verification)
                if (strPIN.toString().equals("1234")) {
                    // Do something...
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIN Matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect PIN!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Required to enable/disable VERIFY button
    private void toggleVerifyButton() {
        if (digitCount == 4)
            buttonVerify.setEnabled(true);
        else
            buttonVerify.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

try this
create layout file like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Verify Number"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Enter Code"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edDigit1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edDigit2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="2"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edDigit3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="3"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edDigit4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="4"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edDigit1, edDigit2, edDigit3, edDigit4;
    Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestSmsPermission();

        edDigit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDigit1);
        edDigit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDigit2);
        edDigit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDigit3);
        edDigit4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDigit4);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        edDigit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (edDigit1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edDigit1.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    edDigit2.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        edDigit2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (edDigit2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edDigit2.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    edDigit3.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        edDigit3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (edDigit3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    edDigit3.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    edDigit4.requestFocus();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (edDigit1.getText().toString().equals("") || edDigit2.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        edDigit3.getText().toString().equals("") || edDigit4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyProfile.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Jalsaa Karroooooooooooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void requestSmsPermission() {
        String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

ask me in case ob any query